# Complex curve:Topology genus and algebraic genus difference?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

This is a question on Gathmann's version 2014 notes on Algebraic Geometry Exercise 0.6.

A polynomial of degree $d$ in two complex variables give rise to a surface of genus $\frac{(d-2)(d-1)}{2}$ where as a polynomial of degree $2n$ give rise to a surface of genus $n-1$. Why these two results do not contradict with each other?

I took d=3 as an example. $z_2^2=(z_1-a)(z_1-b)(z_1-c)$ as a curve in $C^2$ and assume $a,b,c\in R$ with increment ordering. By taking square root, there will be branch cut $[a,b]$ and another cut $[c,\infty)$. After the procedure of 1 point compactification and gluing, I basically obtained a torus with a line segment removed where the line segment is away from the hole. It is basically torus with 1 point removed.

However, there is no reason to believe that $g=\frac{(3-2)(3-1)}{2}=1$ which means 1 hole rather than 2 as I have shown above? Maybe I missed $\delta$ invariants defined on wikipedia for genus of algebraic curves?

It would be better someone could kindly elaborate the point I missed here.

Comment: These are both incorrect. The correct statement can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula : the genus is $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ops. I made a typo here.

Comment: $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ is the genus you get when you work in the projective plane, so for $d = 3$ generically you get a torus, with no points removed.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Suppose the curve is not singular. I could think taking $z_2=\pm\sqrt{(z_1-a)(z_1-b)(z_1-c)}$ living on two different sheets and indentify the corresponding branch cuts $[a,b]$ with $[a,b]$ and $[c,\infty)$ with $[c,\infty)$. Add two points for compactification of each sheet. That is why I obtained a torus with 1 point removed. Somehow, the notes was implying that there is no conflict between the two definition. I think gathmann was trying to say the surface obtained through this procedure is the same as the projectivized variety in terms of genus?